# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'

Tags: python, flask, flask-restful

My intention is to get the int:id from url and store the data to self.user from **init** function. It works for the other functions except for **init**. Is there anything I need to add? or is it not possible?

```
@api.resource('/api/users/<int:id>', endpoint='user')
class UserAPI(Resource):
    def __init__(self, id):
        self.user = User.query.get(id)
        self.reqparse = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.reqparse.add_argument('username', type=str,
            help='No Name Provided', location='json')
        self.reqparse.add_argument('email', type=str,
            help='No Email Provided', location='json')
        self.reqparse.add_argument('password',type=str,
            help='No Password Provided', location="json")
        super(UserAPI, self).__init__()
```

following is the error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\kw\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\kw\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
    response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
  File "C:\Users\kw\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 265, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "C:\Users\kw\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\kw\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 32, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\kw\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\kw\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "C:\Users\kw\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 265, in error_router
    return original_handler(e)
  File "C:\Users\kw\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "C:\Users\kw\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 32, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Users\kw\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\kw\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask_debugtoolbar\__init__.py", line 124, in dispatch_request
    return view_func(**req.view_args)
  File "C:\Users\kw\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask_restful\__init__.py", line 446, in wrapper
    resp = resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kw\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask_httpauth.py", line 61, in decorated
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\kw\Envs\nektime\lib\site-packages\flask\views.py", line 83, in view
    self = view.view_class(*class_args, **class_kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible. Since `Resource` will not be explicitly `init` with other params like `id`. If you look into the code of `flask-restful` and `flask` itself, you will see the `Resource` is kind of like some abstract class, whose functionality mostly depends on `classmethod`.

By the way, `RESTful` means `Representational State Transfer`, which is supposed to be **stateless**. That is, there should not be any different context between different request. Letting the resource to remember the user is violating the design principle of `RESTful` API.